# Eclipse VM Won't Run Java 1.6

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working with Eclipse Indigo on a MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.5.8.  I am trying to run the latest version of the Google Android plugin (version 18) but am receiving the following error when I try to create a new Android project:

> The selected wizard could not be started.
>   Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class  `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectWizard.`
>   Bad version number in .class file

From what I can tell, the issue is that Eclipse is running under a VM with Java version 1.5.  No matter what I do the Eclipse installation details configuration page is reporting:

```
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework

java.class.version=49.0
java.endorsed.dirs=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/endorsed
java.ext.dirs=/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/lib/ext
java.home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home
java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/N-/N-YaOpnxGXqmE8+CqS2VxE+++TI/-Tmp-/
java.library.path=.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition
java.runtime.version=1.5.0_30-b03-389-9M3425
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.specification.version=1.5
```

I have tried setting -vm in the eclipse.ini file and also in Info.plist I added:  -vm/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java

What am I doing wrong?  I'm very frustrated here.

Comment: Have you mover java 6 to the top in the OS X java utility?

Comment: Do you mean in the Java Preferences under Applications/Utility?  I moved Java 1.6 to the top of that utility and then restarted.  I also have my JAVA_HOME set to /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home and my CurrentJDK at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions pointing to 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run the 64-bit Cocoa version of Eclipse 3.5.1, and make sure your JAVA_HOME is set to 1.6.0 and not 1.5.0. Also, set your Preferences->Java->Compiler to 1.6 inside Eclipse.

Comment: That was it.  I had the 32 bit version installed thanks!!  Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to vote up this answer :(